# WPF Binding within text literal

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way to do this in a binding expression:

```
Text="Hello {Binding CurrentUser}"
```

ie:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="#3163AB" Margin="0,0,0,5" 
    FontWeight="Bold" Text="Hello {Binding CurrentUser}" />
```

Obviously I could break it out into two separate textblocks, but this would be much nicer.

Comment: Why do not just split into 2 controls, one with static "Hello" text and another with binded {CurrentUser}? The second just in front of first, obviously.

Comment: @Tigran: for example, for localization.

Comment: I thought of that, but then I'd have to have both text blocks in another horizontal stackPanel to get them to be next to each other, so using strongFormat like the answers below are showing should be much simpler.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of .NET 4, the `Text` property of a `Run` can be bound. I use it all the time:

```
<TextBlock>
    Hello
    <Run Text="{Binding CurrentUser}" />,
    how are you?
</TextBlock>
```

The StringFormat method is nice, but using a Run with a binding allows the use of Value Converters.

Comment: I know I could test this myself, but I don't have SL tools installed...is this `<Run ...>` available in Silverlight 4 too?

Comment: Seems to be! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for the `StringFormat` property of `Binding`.

```
Text="{Binding CurrentUser, StringFormat=Hello {0}}"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Text="{Binding CurrentUser, StringFormat=Hello {0}}"
```

should do.